# How to create AMI from VHD in AWS S3 storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ami, vhd, vmdk

I want to create AMI instance on EC2, where my data sitting on the AWS S3 in VHD/VMDK format.
Could you please help me in how to convert VHD/VMDK to AMI through amazon SDK APIS, 
and how to transfer data from AWS S3 to AMI  through amazon SDK API's

Answer (score 1):

You should use AWS VM Import/Export. You can find the steps (via CLI) in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) and the API is [ImportImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ImportImage.html).

Comment: Thank you sudo for information, can you please clarify another thing that if we have data on the amazon S3 in the slice format that includes boot information and actual data, not in the form of  VHD/VMDK format, how can create AMI from that data in S3

Comment: @vagdevipedalenka I'm afraid I don't follow the question. I believe that you can only import the image formats which are mentioned in:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-image-formats